# Android How to register css file in android project with resource

Tags: android, html, css, image, resources

I got some file from a graphic designer such as CSS, HTML, JSON, SVG, etc for creating an application based on android. However, I don't know how to apply them into an android project. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: well if you know more html than java, i recommend you use phonegab, that use a webview (like browser), it will be easy when you get it, but it isn't native, it is emulate a browser in the app.... but is easy to do something